# Setting up sendmail on a server without webserver

Tags: email, mail-server, sendmail

I want to use `sendmail` so that `fail2ban` can send me notifications. I have read multiple guides on how to set it up, but I cannot get it to work.

What I have done so far:

1. `apt-get install sendmail`
2. Modified `/etc/hosts`: "127.0.0.1       localhost" => "127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain MYHOSTNAME". I think the error could be here. Since I do not have a domainname, the output of `hostname` is the IP-Adress the wrong way round. So if my IP-Adress was `1.2.3.4`, `hostname` outputs `4-3-2-1`. That's what I entered for "MYHOSTNAME".
3. Reboot
4. `sudo sendmailconfig`.

Still, `sendmail` is not sending and `/var/log/mail.log` is empty.

Output of `var/log/syslog` (everything in upper-letters has been modified by me):

```
Jan 17 11:58:11 MY-I-P-ADRESS sendmail[1814]: v0HBwBK4001814: from=fail2ban, size=100100, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201701171158.v0HBwBK4001814@localhost.localdomain>, relay=root@localhost
Jan 17 11:58:11 MY-I-P-ADRESS sendmail[1814]: v0HBwBK4001814: to=MY.MAIL@ADRESS.COM, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=130100, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v0HBwB0U001819 Message accepted for delivery)
Jan 17 11:58:12 MY-I-P-ADRESS sendmail[1799]: v0HBtjwr001799: from=root, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=2, relay=root@localhost
Jan 17 11:58:12 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx3.hotmail.com, version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, bits=256/256
Jan 17 11:58:13 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: v0HBwB0U001819: to=<MY.EMAIL@ADRESS.COM>, delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=220357, relay=mx3.hotmail.com. [65.55.37.120], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jan 17 11:58:13 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: v0HBwB0U001819: to=<fail2ban@localhost.localdomain>, delay=00:00:02, mailer=local, pri=220357, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 17 11:58:13 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: v0HBwB0U001819: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:02, mailer=local, pri=220357, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 17 11:58:13 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: v0HBwD0U001821: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 17 11:58:13 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: v0HBwD0U001821: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 17 11:58:13 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: v0HBwD0V001821: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 17 11:58:13 MY-I-P-ADRESS sm-mta[1821]: v0HBwD0U001821: Saved message in /var/lib/sendmail/dead.letter
```

Comment: You should use `ssmtp`.

Comment: Does it work with fail2ban?

Comment: Does it say something in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @FatalMerlin Oh yes, actually there is something. I added it to my post.

Comment: @Bobface hm, I don't think that the hostname should have anything to do with it. Try to send a test email with `echo "This is a Testmail :)" | mailx user@mailserver.tld` (Install mailx with `sudo apt-get install mailutils` if you don't have it)

Comment: @FatalMerlin I just noticed `dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable` in the 5th line. Does that mean that there is something wrong with the dns name resolution?

Comment: @Bobface Please try to reconfigure sendmail using [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When you typed in `sudo sendmailconfig`, you should have been
>   prompted to configure sendmail.
>
> For reference, the files that are updated during configuration are
>   located at the following (in case you want to update them manually):
>
> ```
> /etc/mail/sendmail.conf
> /etc/cron.d/sendmail
> /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
> ```
>
> You can test sendmail to see if it is properly configured and setup by
>   typing the following into the command line:
>
> ```
> $ echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@domain.com
> ```
>
> The following will allow you to add smtp relay to sendmail:
>
> ```
> #Change to your mail config directory:
> cd /etc/mail
>
> #Make a auth subdirectory
> mkdir auth
> chmod 700 auth
>
> #Create a file with your auth information to the smtp server
> cd auth
> touch client-info
>
> #In the file, put the following, matching up to your Internet Service Provider's smtp server:
> AuthInfo:your.isp.net "U:root" "I:user" "P:password"
>
> #Generate the Authentication database, make both files readable only by root
> makemap hash client-info < client-info
> chmod 600 client-info
> cd ..
>
> #Add the following lines to sendmail.mc. Make sure you update your smtp server
> define(`SMART_HOST',`your.isp.net')dnl
> define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
> FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash /etc/mail/auth/client-info')dnl
>
> #Invoke creation sendmail.cf
> m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
>
> #Restart the sendmail daemon
> service sendmail restart
> ```

[Copied from *sendmail: how to configure sendmail on ubuntu?* on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359510/4468328), answer by [**Venice**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359291/venice), but modified to [change opening `'` quotes to `` ` ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808170/1038860). (That question was too old to migrate here.)

Comment: How do I find out what I have to enter for `your.isp.net`?

Comment: Search on the home page of your Internet service provider for "SMTP Server"

Comment: It is a rented server hosted by a company. How can I find out their ISP? Is there a way to find it out with commands or do I have to contact them?

Comment: you have to search their web site or ask them through a support ticket.

Comment: Don't thank me @Bobface, just press the little grey checkmark to the left of the question turning it to a beautiful green!  ;)

Comment: I will now try it out, if it works I will of course :)

Comment: ´m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf´ prints `m4:sendmail.mc:102: cannot open `/usr/share/sendmail/cf/feature/'authinfo'.m4': No such file or directory`. I followed your guide step by step.

Comment: Oops, my fault. Works now!

Comment: Fabby, @Bobface: Does this work, as written? Unlike most languages, [quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Quoted-strings) in [M4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)) are [*opened* by a backtick (`\``)](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/intro_m4.html) and closed by a single quote (`'`), unless [changed with `changequote`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Changequote). [On SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10359437), some users [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808170) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002751) about that.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes exactly, that was the mistake. Although I thought that I accidently changed it so I wrote "my mistake" although it was already like this in Fabbys answer. :) I will edit it now.

Comment: @bobface.  Dzmn, you're quick!  My turn to thank you now!  :-)  +5 rep again...